# Propose creating a new-york-state tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

(I lack the rep to create tags.) I noticed there was no tag applicable to NY State in the US, though there are for some other states (eg [georgia](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/georgia)). NY is home to the Adirondacks, Catskills, a portion of the AT, etc. so I would think there should be ample value in such a tag.

I don't know if the naming convention disallows the `-state` portion but disambiguating from NY City seems valuable.

Comment: Typically we create tags when there is a need, ie multiple questions that would be helped by having such a tag. Are there enough questions to warrant that tag, currently?